# Solr new start command after upgrading from 4.7 to 7.1

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene

I just upgraded our solr from 4.7 to 7.1.
In previous version, we start solr with the following command:

```
nohup java -DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=my_solr_key -Xms500m -Xmx500m -jar start.jar
```

What is the equivalent command for the new solr version?

I ran `bin/solr start` but:

1. It loaded with default parameters and not with the parameters it used to (`-DSTOP.PORT=8079 -DSTOP.KEY=my_solr_key -Xms500m -Xmx500m`). I need to specify these parameters in the start command (I don't want to change files in the solr installation folders).
2. I got the following errors (repeated every few seconds):

   ```
   Creating Solr home directory /exlibris/sfx_ver/app/solr-7.1.0/example/cloud/node1/solr
   Cloning /exlibris/sfx_ver/app/solr-7.1.0/example/cloud/node1 into
   /exlibris/sfx_ver/app/solr-7.1.0/example/cloud/node2

   Starting up Solr on port 8983 using command:
   "bin/solr" start -cloud -p 8983 -s "example/cloud/node1/solr"

   Waiting up to 180 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: C
   lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: P
   lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: :
   lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: L
   lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: I
   lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: S
   lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: T
   lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: E
   lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: N
   lsof 4.78
    latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/
    latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ
    latest man page: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man
    usage: [-?abhlnNoOPRstUvVX] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-f[gG]] [+|-e s]
    [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+m [m]] [+|-M] [-o [o]]
    [-p s] [+|-r [t]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [-Z [Z]] [--] [names]
   Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information.
    [\]  lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: C
   lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: P
   lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: :
   lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: L
   lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: I
   lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: S
   lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: T
   lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: E
   lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: N
   lsof 4.78
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ```

Comment: For the startup errors - my guess is that you're on SUSE. There's [an open ticket for that issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7998). For how to configure Solr as a service with the most recent version, see [Taking Solr to Production](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/taking-solr-to-production.html).

Comment: I found that it was related to the lsof version with is too old. older version doesn't support 'LISTEN' command.